# Cannot Access PySpark Column with Name that has a period . in the name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to access a dataframe column, but am getting weird errors that I can't access a column.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
tmp = spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], "string").toDF("3p21.31")
display(tmp.select(col("3p21.31")))
```

but this gives an error:

`AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`3p21.31`' given input columns: [3p21.31];;`

which seems to be contradicting.

I have also tried escaping the period, `tmp.select(col(3p21\.31))` to no avail.

How can I access a column that has a `.` in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work even using the grave accent ***`*** to wrap the name of the column, like below

```
tmp = spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], "string").toDF("`3p21.31`")
display(tmp.select(col("`3p21.31`")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a raw string:

```
tmp = spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], "string").toDF(r"3p21.31")
display(tmp.select(col("3p21.31")))
```

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work.  Also, the data file that I'm using comes from a JSON, so I don't think that I can modify the column titles before I load the JSON